# How to Remove Specific object from firebase Realtime Database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How to remove specific object from Firebase DB. I want to remove `fine` message from `champdecay@gmail.com` username.

[image]

**I have tried following code and i got proper object but remove() not works.**

```
abcd = ref.orderByChild('message').equalTo('fine');
abcd.on('value', function(abcdSnap){
    console.log(abcdSnap.val());
})
```

above Code returns `-L-Kl8ctoi5j4TtMWTsc` but now how to remove this object. i tried to remove() as follows but not working...

```
abcd = ref.orderByChild('message').equalTo('fine').remove();

abcd.on('value', function(abcdSnap){
   abcdSnap.remove();
})
```

Comment: Show the code where you tried to remove()

Comment: see edited question... @DoesData

Answer (score 1):

Okay Finally Got the Answer.

```
abcd = ref.orderByChild('message').equalTo(msg);
abcd.on('value', function(abcdSnap){
    var a = abcdSnap.val();
    var b = Object.keys(a)[0];
    ref.child(b).remove();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void removeUserData()
{
    databaseReferenceC = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users/profiles/");
    FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
    databaseReferenceC.child(user.getUid()).removeValue();
}
```

as a example you can use something like that use `removeValue()`